# How to randomly create a form from a specified list of forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write a code that pops up a random form from a specified list of forms when a button is pressed in winforms.

The forms in the specified list include **Form1, Form2, and Form3.**
It must not be created to a form other than the specified forms.

The code I'm using now works using `switch()` and `if()`. However, when increasing or decreasing the number of Forms, it is cumbersome to modify all kinds of places.

I know how to create the form.

```cs
private void ChangeForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var form = new Form1();
  form.ShowDialog();
}
```

**The part I'm stuck on is that I'm not sure what to do when I use the `new` keyword to specify the form I want to create.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the names of the forms in a list and select the name at a random index. Once you have a type name, you use Reflection to create an instance of that type. That is something that you can search how to do for yourself. This is an example of why it's important to break a problem down into parts. Random selection from a list and object creation using Reflection are completely independent of each other.

Comment: You could actually put the `Types` themselves in a list rather than the names, e.g. `var formTypes = new[] {typeof(Form1), typeof(Form2)};`. Once you have a `Type`, you can pass it to a method that creates an instance of that type via Reflection.

Comment: If the number of types is fairly small, another option would be to write a method for creating each one and then create delegates for those methods and put them into a list. You can then select a delegate at a random index and invoke it.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however… when you say… _“I know how to change the form.”_ … then show the code you have posted, then you are mistaken about “changing” anything… that code simply creates a “NEW” `Form1`… every time the code executes a NEW form is created and "changes" nothing with respect to any previously created forms.

Comment: @JohnG Oh, I will correct your post based on your comments.

Comment: @John As you suggested, I will try to solve it. Thank you for your valuable words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider creating a list of `Func<Form>` and then selecting randomly from the list to create your `Form`. The advantage with a `Func<Form>` is that you can incorporate more complex initialization and the advantage with a `List<>` is that you can dynamically add more `Form` factories at run-time.

Something like this:

```
private Random _random = new Random();

private List<Func<Form>> _formFactories = new List<Func<Form>>()
{
    () => new Form2(),
    () => new Form3()
    {
        Text = "My Caption",
    },
    () => new Form4(),
}

private void ChangeForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = _formFactories[_random.Next(0, _formFactories.Count)].Invoke();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Much simpler and more dynamic! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`.

You only need to create a separate value for the `type` parameter.

The reason for creating a `random` object in a field is to ensure randomness by creating it only once.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowDialogRandomForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formsType = CreateFormsType();
        var randomNumber = random.Next(0, formsType.Length);
        var randomFormType = formsType[randomNumber];
        var randomForm = Activator.CreateInstance(randomFormType) as Form;

        randomForm?.ShowDialog();
    }

    private Type[] CreateFormsType()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(Form1), typeof(Form2), typeof(Form3) };
    }
}
```

If you want to change the specified list of forms, you only need to modify the `CreateFormsType()` method.